# Detect closer point inside a view from touch

Tags: objective-c, ios

There's a way to, when the user touches outside the view, the app detects the closer point inside this view? I want to detect just like the image below.

[image: Example]

EDIT:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

if (CGRectContainsPoint([_grayView frame], touchPoint)) {
    // The touch was inside the gray view
} else {
    // The touch was outside the view. Detects where's the closer CGPoint inside the gray view.
    // The detection must be related to the whole view (In the image example, the CGPoint returned would be related to the whole screen)
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the touch is inside the square? And are you interested in the shortest length from the point to the square?

Comment: @Martol1ni, I'm detecting when the user touches inside the square with the `CGRectContainsPoint` condition. Else (if the user touches outside), the app must recognize what's the point - CGPoint, (inside the square [UIView]), that is closer to the touch.

Comment: Provide some code for the `CGRectContainsPoint`, and I will look at it. I do not really get what you mean by "get the point in the square that is closer to the touch". Do you mean, when you touch the point you have drawn in the top-left of your image, it should return (0,0) relative to your grey square? Or the actual CGPoint of the whole screen?

Comment: @Martol1ni, the point returned must be related to the whole UIView point. Check the edit, I post the `CGRectContainsPoint` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static float bound(float pt, float min, float max)
{
    if(pt < min) return min;
    if(pt > max) return max;
    return pt;
}

static CGPoint boundPoint(CGPoint touch, CGRect bounds)
{
    touch.x = bound(touch.x, bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width;
    touch.y = bound(touch.y, bounds.origin.y, bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height;
    return touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a little math:

1. Ask the touch for its `locationInView:` with the view in question as the argument.
2. Compare the point’s `x` with the view’s `bounds`, clamping to the extrema of that `CGRect`.
3. There is no step three, the result of the above is the point you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
CGPoint pt = [touches locationInView:childView];
if(pt.x >= 0 && pt.x <= childView.frame.size.width 
&& pt.y >= 0 && pt.y <= childView.frame.size.height) {
   NSLog(@"Touch inside rect");
   return;
}
pt.x = MIN(childView.frame.size.width, MAX(0, pt.x));
pt.y = MIN(childView.frame.size.height, MAX(0, pt.y));
// and here is the point
NSLog(@"The closest point is %f, %f", pt.x, pt.y);
```

Comment: MAX(0. pt.x) should be MAX(0, pt.x)